# Any way to change my review of suggested edit?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

I goofed and rejected a suggested edit, a vote that was actually directed at the previous edit that I was reviewing. As this is unfair to the user who posted the suggested edit in question, is there any way in which to change/cancel my reject?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't change your decision.

However, don't feel too bad about it. No one will scowl you for getting one wrong (That's why you need 3 reviewers anyway).

Comment: And assuming the OP is referring to [this edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/1681290), it was approved anyhow, so there was no harm done.

Comment: Thanks. I still feel bad about it, though. :-P